# Need Help getting a specific value from a JSON key/value pair

Tags: c#, json, httprequest

I am pulling data from a 3rd party API and have myself some code that looks like this...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int playSystem = 2;
    string playID = "";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void xBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        playSystem = 1;
    }

    public void playstation_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        playSystem = 2;
    }

    private async void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        statDisplay.Clear();

        var userName = nameBox.Text;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-API-KEY", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

            var response = await client.GetAsync("https://bungie.net/platform/Destiny/SearchDestinyPlayer/" + playSystem + "/" + userName);
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            dynamic item = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);

            statDisplay.AppendText(item.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of displaying all the information in the object as a string, I would like to take a specific value from that object, store it into a variable, and use that variable in another HTTPRequest.

The output I am getting looks like this...

```
{
  "Response": [
    {
      "iconPath": "/img/theme/destiny/icons/icon_psn.png",
      "membershipType": 2,
      "membershipId": "01234567890",
      "displayName": "xxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  ],
  "ErrorCode": 1,
  "ThrottleSeconds": 0,
  "ErrorStatus": "Success",
  "Message": "Ok",
  "MessageData": {}
}
```

I would like to specifically focus on the membershipId key/value.

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: What did you try to get the specific value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var membershipId = (string)item.Response[0].membershipId;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking to do can be found in Newtonsoft's Documentation here

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm

In this example they are using linq to find specific things on the Object, but you can also For Each through each element within your return object.